# Netsuite - setting entity label in dropdown list to ID - Name - Phone etc?

Tags: netsuite

Currently we have the problem in the screenshot below-

[image]

I know we can set the label on our own custom fields, but this one is the entity on a sales order, how would we set the label content to something - say "ID Name Phone" etc to help differentiate when searching?

I have searched high and low but can't find it anywhere.

Comment: A customized form has a spot for a custom label for each field. Not as easy compared to custom fields where you can change the caption in the the custom field definition and apply it to all custom forms but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a custom label for a field on each customized form individually.

[image]